# How to space out items in a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create a toolbar that looks like:

[image]

How can I do this in XML? Here is what mine looks like currently:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/toolbarLinearLayout" android:background="@color/solid_yellow">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/replyButton" android:text="Reply"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="RT" android:id="@+id/rtButton"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/dmButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="DM"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might want the padding attribute of the LinearLayout, e.g.

```
android:padding="5dip"
```

To get the items to each take up the same amount of space, use layout_weight, e.g.

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/toolbarLinearLayout" android:background="@color/solid_yellow">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/replyButton" android:text="Reply"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="RT" android:id="@+id/rtButton"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/dmButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="DM"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

As long as all the elements have the same weight they should take up the same space. layout_width="fill_parent" will ensure the whole bar is filled.

Comment: That will pad it all around. Which is fine, but I want the distance to the left and right to be equidistant and more prominently spaced out like the image above.

Comment: I tried adding paddingLeft & paddingRight but the space between the buttons aren't being padded

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer slightly - hopefully this is more along the lines of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Define your toolbar something like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button android:id="@+id/replyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button ...
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <!-- etc. -->
</LinearLayout>
```

All the extra space will be allocated to the transparent views between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_margin="some value" for item in linearlayout.This worked for me.